# Refere to object in object by interpolation (Angular 2+)

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have a data structure like this:

```
post : {
 content: 'content',
 creator: {
  name: 'Jones',
  id: 1,
  avatar: 'jones.png'
 }
}
```

In HTML i want to display by interpolation for example the name of the creator.

I tried that:

```
{{ post.creator.name }}
```

But in app, at this place is an empty field.

Comment: could you please paste your controller or class file of the component

Comment: what exactly is the problem here? `name` has value but still, it is not appearing in HTML.

Comment: @ashishpal true, I want to make it appears in html

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare `object` as below:

```
 post = {
  content: 'content',
  creator: {
   name: 'Jones',
   id: 1,
   avatar: 'jones.png'
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

You can declare type to object
`post:Post={...}`

Then declare classes:

```
export class Post  {
 content:string;
 creator:Creator
}
export class Creator  {
  name: string;
  id: number;
  avatar: string;
}
```

[Working code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/hello-angular-6-fmadfp?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: You don't need to specify post: any. The problem is that OP did not set post equal to the object (post = { content... }).

Comment: @לבני מלכה but what if I create object by constructor? post = new Post( { ... })?

Comment: not neede `new` only `:Post` : `post:Post={}` :https://stackblitz.com/edit/hello-angular-6-fmadfp?file=src/app/app.component.ts